# pandas.DataFrame.apply does not behave as described in the documentation

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Today, I was trying to understand all the subtleties of the **pandas.DataFrame.apply** and I tried to go through its documentation as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply):

In order to understand what the argument `result_type` does I made up the following simple example:

First, I defined a custom function called **plus_2** in the following way:

```
def plus_2(x):
    y =[]
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        y.append(x[i]+2)
    return y
```

Then, I used the same DataFrame that the documentation uses:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,9]]*3, columns = ["A", "B"])
df
```

In order to understand the difference between `result_type = "expand"` and `result_type = "reduce"` I ran the following codes:

1. `df_col = df.apply(plus_2, axis = 0, raw = False, result_type="reduce")`
2. `df_col1 = df.apply(plus_2, axis = 0, raw = True, result_type="reduce")`

The results from the first is just a Series object, while the results from the second code is a DataFrame object as you can see on the picture and you can replicate it as well.

[image]

My confusion is the following:

As the documentation says when `raw = True` each row or column is passed as ndarray while when `raw = False` *(which is default)* each row or column is passed as a Series object.

At the same time, when the argument `result_type = "reduce"` the list-like results are not expanded but retuned as a Series if possible.

I do not understand why the result from the first code is the Series object while the result from the second one is the DataFrame. In other words, or in the documentations' words, I do not understand why it is possible to return list-like results as Series when each column is passed as Series (`raw = False`) while it is not possible when each columns is passed as ndarray (`raw = True`)? Shouldn't it be other way around?

P.S.

I am using pandas version 1.2.4

Comment: "These only act when axis=1 (columns)"

Comment: As @It_is_Chris outlines the `result_type` argument does not matter here (since `axis=0`). You are only seeing the difference between `raw=True` vs `raw=False`.

Comment: Well, that's another issue I am going to write about. You will not see the difference between `raw=True` and `raw=False` for any other value of the argument 'result_type'. If you want to convince yourself try `result_type = expand`  or `result_type = broadcast` and the results will be the same no matter `raw`'s value. Hence, "These only act when axis=1 (columns)" for `result_type` is not true.

Comment: @HenryEcker See my comment above